# Is there a simple way to switch between using and ignoring metacharacters in Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, metacharacters

Is there a way of toggling the compilation or use of metacharacters when compiling regexes?  The current code looks like this:

**Current code:**

```
import re

the_value  = '192.168.1.1'
the_regex  = re.compile(the_value)

my_collection = ['192a168b1c1', '192.168.1.1']

my_collection.find_matching(the_regex)

result = ['192a168b1c1', '192.168.1.1']
```

**The ideal solution would look like**:

```
import re

the_value  = '192.168.1.1'
the_regex  = re.compile(the_value, use_metacharacters=False)

my_collection = ['192a168b1c1', '192.168.1.1']

my_collection.find_matching(the_regex)

result = ['192.168.1.1']
```

The ideal solution would let the `re` library handle the disabling of metacharacters, to avoid having to get involved in the process as much as possible.

Comment: if you're looking for a static string, why do you want to use the re module? Why not just compare strings for equality, or search for a substring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. However:

```
the_regex  = re.compile(re.escape(the_value))
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function for this.

> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape('192.168.1.1')
'192\\.168\\.1\\.1'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm accepting Ignacio's answer because it's technically the full solution.  However, I appreciate your answer and your help :).

Comment: Whereas I think this is the better answer as it links to and quotes the documentation…